# How to insert python variable inside the value of a form?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make a timer that gets its time from a python variable. But whatever I am doing it's not working.
Here is my python piece of code.

```
@blogs.route('/individual_set/<int:set_id>')
def individual_set(set_id):
    individual_page = Post.query.get_or_404(set_id)
    return render_template('forms_page.html', individual_page=individual_page,time_limit = 25)
```

According to the above code, I am wanting to make the  input value to **time_limit = 25**
Here is the HTML part

```
  <input name = 'set_time' type="hidden" id="set-time" value='1'>
  <div id="countdown">
    <div id="tiles" class="color-full"></div>
  </div>
```

Inserting **{{time_limit}}** does not work whereas plain value like **value ='5'** works

Comment: All the Flask/Jinja2 examples I found do have spaces inside the curly braces, like so: `{{ time_limit }}` ... might that be the problem? Or do you have a different templating language than Jinja2 set up in Flask?

Comment: Yeah, it's a good practice to do {{ time_limit }}. And cause now it works I am more confused than it is also working with {{time_limit}}. It was maybe the cause of any other mistake of mine. Anyways thank you for looking at my messy code. From now on  I will try to follow better coding practices.  And maybe doing so won't make me ask silly questions hereThanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing {{ time_limit }} instead of {{time_limit}} worked.

Comment: Came here again because i messed things again